# Error running ImageMagick from R: Invalid Parameter - 80

Tags: r, imagemagick

I am using Windows 7 on a 32 bit computer. I have installed ImageMagick-7.0.4-4-Q16-x86-dll.exe. I have added path to ImageMagick in Path of Environmetal Variables. Using convert --version in command prompt shows ImageMagick correctly (but not when I run it in R using system()). Now, I try to make an animated gif file using the following R code (taken from another stackoverflow post):

```
    library(animation)
    ani.options('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.4-Q16/convert.exe')
    dir.create("examples")
    setwd("examples")

    png(file="example%02d.png",width=200, height=200)
    for(i in c(10:1,"GO!")){
        plot.new()
        text(.5,.5,i,cex=6)
    }
    dev.off()
```

No error message shows as of yet. But when I write the following line:

```
    system("convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif")
```

it throws the following error:

> Invalid parameter - 80
>   Warning message: 
>   running command 'convert -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif' had status 4

After this, I ran the following command

```
    system("convert --version")
```

and it throws the following error:

> Invalid drive specification
>   Warning message:
>   running command 'convert --version' had status 4

I tried to solve this by running RStudio in administrator mode but in vain.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using the ImageMagick command, and not the Windows system tool? They have the same name.

Comment: I am not sure whether I am using ImageMagick command or Windows system tool. How can I know that?

Comment: I just turned on my Windows machine - you are definitely using the Windows command, not the imageMagick command. This should help you: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/#convert_issue

Comment: To know which are you using, use `Sys.which("convert")`. My guess (agreeing with @Chrisss) is that it'll return something like `"C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\convert.exe"`. It's a good thing `convert` doesn't do anything permanent, like *"convert a FAT volume to NTFS"* (ref: `system("help convert")` on windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Microsoft tool called `CONVERT.EXE` that has clashed with the **ImageMagick** tool of the same name for years.

Version 7 of **ImageMagick** has a new command-name, namely `magick`, which you can use in place of `convert`, `identify` `mogrify` and the other commands in the **ImageMagick** suite.

---

So,

```
identify image.png
```

becomes

```
magick identify image.png
```

---

And

```
convert image.png -resize 10x10 result.png
```

becomes

```
magick image.png -resize 10x10 result.png
```

---

- Apart from that, you need to ensure that the PATH that **R** is using includes the directory that contains `magick.exe`.
- You also need to ensure that the `system()` shell is running in the directory where your images are, so you can check where it is running like this:

  system("pwd")
- If it is not running in the directory where your images are, you can either use an absolute path to your images (i.e. one that begins from the top of the drive, like "C:\User\Fred\FunkyImages\Image1.jpg") or you can change directory inside the `system()` command before you do your processing:

  system("cd somewhere && do something")

Comment: Using magick instead of convert did the trick for me. Thanks!